# Background Image Resizing Issue

Tags: css, image, background, resize, fixed

On mobile, my background image looks like this when the body is set to (position:fixed).

[image]

This is what the background image looks like when the body is set to (position:relative).

[image]

You can tell that when the body is set to (position:fixed) it tends to be more zoomed out than the other ,and I'm not sure why this problem is occurring.The problem only occurs on mobile as well.It is supposed to look like the second image which looks correct but it is much more zoomed out than the second image. Here is the main code for this:

**Html:**

```
<body>
 <div class="background">
  <div class="hero">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

**Css:**

```
 body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }

 /* Background Space */

 .background {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

 /* Background Image */

 .hero {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:50% 50%;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
 }
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with this new code, and start fiddling around. Let me know what you come up with. A lot of the stuff you are using as properties don't even do anything in the case that you are using it. For example, setting top, left, bottom, and right for an element that has position relative, does nothing. You would want to use those properties for something with position absolute.

You can get a full height background-image with much less verbage. Try the snippet below first.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#hero {
  background: url('../img/hero.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -10;
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the background-attachment. I just tested it without background-attachment:fixed and worked fine with position:fixed on the body.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Using @media query**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
     .hero {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMCdB.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
 }
```

**Note:** change window resize and i hope your accepted output is there. in Live Demo. **max  width set background in mobile device .**

**Live** [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/cc3ndgco/)